# Expression Blend 4 and .NET 4 Platform Update (.NET 4.0.1)

Tags: .net, expression-blend, platform-update-1

After changing the target framework of my WPF project to ".NET Framework 4 Platform Update 1" in Visual Studio, Expression Blend 4 does not show the design view of my files, just XAML code, and it will not compile the project. Using Platform Update 1 (ie. .NET 4.0.1) is absolutely necessary because we are using "WF State Machine" which is only available in this Update. Anyone with a solution for this?

TIA
Heiko

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I typically solve this problem.  Sorry I don't have an exact answer of "put this guid here", but on the plus side now you'll know how to solve it the next time it happens.

Create a new WPF project that targets just .NET 4.  Diff that csproj file with your Platform Update 1 csproj.  You'll most likely see different ProjectTypeGuids between the two.  Copy the one that is present in the .NET 4 project and add it to the list in the Platform Update 1 project.  I'll bet that you can now open the design view in Blend.